# Integrating QuickSight dashboard with authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, amazon-cognito, amazon-quicksight

I have created a Quicksight dash board. I need to integrate dashboard with my react, node  js application now. When I am trying to integrate it with my front end I am getting popup window to login. My users are in Cognito user pool. I gave my user name and password for quick sight here and I am getting my quick sight refused to  connect[image: .]

I did not find a tutorial to integrating my quicksight with react and pass my authentication details without loggin again. My users are in Cognito user pool. Can someone explain how to integrate the Quicksight dashboard with the react application or suggest a tutorial to do that.
I need to integrate Quicksight with react application and my back end is nest js.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this error, I have to allow my domain name in the Quicksight. After allowing my domain name now I can see my dash board.